# Help identify this window

Tags: windows

We would like to replace our windows, but we couldn't find the window manufacturer through the NAMI sticker. I have emailed NAMI but didn't get a reply either. Could someone help identify this windows? Thank you[image][image]

Comment: If the intent is to replace the window, you do not need to know the manufacturer. Being so old as to need replacement the new windows, even from the same manufacturer, will not be of the same exact design , due to code and material changes.  Please state why you need to know the manufacturer if it is something other than a sizing question.

Comment: Some of the glass panels have fogged up over the years and I'd like to contact the manufacturer and see if I can order replacements. What would you suggest in this case I should do?

Comment: Contact any glass specialist. They should be able to cut or order the glass you need. Double pane glass that is fogged means the seal has broken.  My neighbor has just encountered the same thing.  They contacted the company that installed the windows.  As well as another window company and a glass specialist.  The price to replace the glass among all 3 was within $45.  There is no advantage to finding the manufacturer.